# How can I update a list of checkboxes via Ajax without unchecking them

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider the following list of checkboxes - a list of online and a list of offline users;

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<div id="users">
<h2>Online</h2>
<ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="userId[]" value="1" /> Joe Bloggs</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="userId[]" value="2" /> Bill Gates</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="userId[]" value="3" /> John Smith</li>
</ul>
<h2>Offline</h2>
<ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="userId[]" value="4" /> The Queen</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="userId[]" value="5" /> Steve Jobs</li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

The user can check the online users and then perform an action such as sending them (1 or more) an email - but I need the list to update dynamically as users log in and out of the system.

The code I am using to update the list every 20 seconds or so is something like this;

```
$("#users").load("/path/to/my/users/load.php");
```

but obviously this simply replaces the HTML in the "users" div and un-checks any "online" boxes that were checked by the user (which is annoying if the user hasn't yet performed the action).

So in short; I'm struggling to write the necessary code in jQuery that can fetch a list of online and offline users, add/remove them from the lists while keeping the checked values intact in the "online" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Wrap your lists in a form
2) Serialize the selected checkboxes
3) Perform your DOM replacement
4) Iterate through the selected checkboxes and reapply them

```
var checked = $('#users form').serializeArray();
//perform ajax call

//in the ajax success function after replacing the DOM
$.each(checked, function(i, data) {
  $('input[name="'+data.name+'"][value="'+data.value+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a different approach: instead of `.load()`, use, say, `$.getJSON()` to retrieve an object which looks like:

```
{
    online: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Joe Bloggs'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Bill Gates'},
        {id: 3, name: 'John Smith'}
    ],
    offline: [
        {id: 4, name: 'The Queen'},
        {id: 5, name: 'Steve Jobs'}
    ]
}
```

and update HTML yourself, using the existing checkbox if present for that user ID.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest, +1 for being faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could save in a global var when they are changed (onClick), and after the `.load`, using the callback/something else, recheck them.

Answer (score 0):

Load the online/offline users using ajax, and move the elements around depending on their status. My take on this:

```
// Define all users    
var allUsers = {users:[
            {id: 1, name: 'Joe Bloggs'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Bill Gates'},
            {id: 3, name: 'John Smith'},
            {id: 4, name: 'The Queen'},
            {id: 5, name: 'Steve Jobs'}
        ]
    };

    // Define which users are online
    var onlineUser = [2,3,5,12,76];


    $.each(allUsers.users,function(id,user){
        $('<input />').attr('type','checkbox').attr('name','userId[]').val(user.id).attr('disabled','disabled').appendTo($('<li />').text(user.name).appendTo($('#offline')));  

           });






    // function to update which users are online
    function reloadUsers(onlineUsers){
        $('#online li input').attr('disabled','disabled').parent().appendTo($('#offline'));
        $.each(onlineUsers, function(id,user){

            $('#offline [value="'+user+'"]').attr('disabled',false).parent().appendTo($('#online'));
        });

    }
// load online users on document load
reloadUsers(onlineUser);

// just used in the text example to show how to update online users
$("#reload").click(function(){
       reloadUsers($("textarea").val().split(","))
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/4zde9/